# Vector-valued Weierstrass theorem

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, vector-analysis, approximation-theory, weierstrass-approximation

I'm looking for a version of Weierstrass's approximation theorem that works for a continuous function $f:D \to \mathbb{R}^d$.

**Versions that I know of**

[Multivariate Weierstrass theorem?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1036439/multivariate-weierstrass-theorem) uses a generalization of Weierstrass for multivariate domain based on the Stone's generalization of the theorem.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem) gives several versions but none (as far as i read) works with a multivariate image.

**What I need it for**

I need it to properly justify [Proof of Peano's existence theorem for ODEs](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1911265/proof-of-peanos-existence-theorem-for-odes?rq=1) or [Proving Peano's Existence Theorem by approximating with $C^{\infty}$ functions using Weierstrass' Theorem.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2541579/proving-peanos-existence-theorem-by-approximating-with-c-infty-functions-u)

Seen the above application that I'm seeking I think that perhaps I can do it component-wise. (????)

**Statement of the (possible) theorem**

Let $D \subseteq \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}^d$ be an open set and $f:D \to \mathbb{R}^d$ a continuous function.

$\exists.p_n:D \to \mathbb{R}^d$ a sequence of polynomials such that $p_n \stackrel{\|\cdot\|_{\infty}}{\to} f$ on a compact set of the form $[a,b] \times \overline{B}(x_0,b) \subseteq D$.

Comment: http://acadpubl.eu/monographs/201301/1012732acadpubl.201301.pdf seems a good place to start, althougth i would like the theorem restated in my easy conditions, perhaps theorem 4.3.1

Comment: State the version you would like to hold.

Comment: Why not just use Stone Weierstrass on each coordinate function of $f?$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this simple case will help: Suppose $f=(f_1,\dots,f_k):\mathbb R^j\to \mathbb R^k$ is continuous. By Stone-Weierstrass, for each $m$ there exist polynomials $p_{m1}, \cdots, p_{mk}$ such that

$$|p_{mi}-f_i| < 1/m\,\, \text { on } \overline {B(0,m)},\, i=1,\dots, k.$$

Set $p_m = (p_{m1},\dots , p_{mk}).$ Then $p_m\to f$ uniformly on compact subsets of $\mathbb R^j.$